# transferring procedural php to laravel php

Tags: javascript, css

I have a nav bar with a button for online users. What is does is once it click. It will pop the right bar. When I transfer it from PHP core (procedural) to laravel. It doesn't work anymore.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
    <span class="icon mdi mdi-notifications"></span>
    <span class="indicator"></span>
</a>
```

This is the right side-bar

```
<nav class="be-right-sidebar">
    <div class="sb-content">
      <div class="tab-navigation">

      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Even if I change the '#' to '/' . It is still the same. maybe I miss something or miss understand. I hope could explain to me.. This CSS and JS are from beagle.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with server side code. Are you sure your css & js files are correctly loaded?

Comment: yea. i added it correctly.  in the public folder. i paste all the css/js/lib/img. then adding {{asset('JS or CSS')}} bracket2 or something.

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('lib/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}" ></script>

Comment: now my notification and account doesn't work now. all of it not working